# insmod Unknown symbol in module

Tags: linux, memory, fault

I'm trying to port edac module into kernel and get the following error:

```
> insmod /lib/modules/2.6.34.12/kernel/drivers/edac/edac_core.ko
insmod: error inserting '/lib/modules/2.6.34.12/kernel/drivers/edac/edac_core.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

The following is the dmesg log:

```
edac_core: no symbol version for "function"
edac_core: Unknown symbol "function"
```

Comment: does google help:? http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-September/003260.html

Comment: despite `EXPORT_SYMBOL`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392611/unknown-symbol-in-module-on-module-insertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be couple of reason for this error. One of them might be symbol named "function" is exported as GPL only. Or may be kernel against which you are loading your module does not have that "function" symbol, but it is in some other kernel version.

Comment: The symbol for "function" is not exported as GPL only. An entry for the exported symbol also exists in `kallsyms`. I'm sure there could be no licensing mistake as `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` is already included in my module. With `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y`, I get this warning: `WARNING: "function" [drivers/edac/edac_core.ko] has no CRC!` though the CRC of other symbols are proper. How could I remove this warning?

Comment: May be this thread can help you:https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/8/27/202. At the end of discussion in it, it changes CONFIG_PHYSICAL_ALIGN from 0x100000 to 0x1000000 in kernel config.