# "Unknown symbol in module" on module insertion despite EXPORT_SYMBOL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to compile and insert the r8169 realtek ethernet driver. My kernel version is

```
ebin@sony:~$ uname -r
4.2.0-rc3-custom
```

I have the full source of the same in my local disk, which is used to install the current kernel. The module compiles successfully when I run   `make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`modules`
but when I insert the module, it shows

```
ebin@sony:~/linux_testing/linux-stable/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek$ sudo insmod r8169.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module r8169.ko: Unknown symbol in module
ebin@sony:~/linux_testing/linux-stable/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek$ dmesg
[16717.311216] r8169: Unknown symbol mii_ethtool_gset (err 0)
```

When I grepped through the source, I found

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mii_ethtool_gset);
```

already exported in the `mii.c`. So I guess it is not the problem of unexported symbol. Let me know if I have to provide any other info. Please help.

Comment: Did you copy the "Module.symvers" into the build directory?

Comment: @ebin: If `mii` is compiled as a module, you need to insert it (`sudo modprobe mii`) before inserting your module. Unlike to `modprobe`, `insmod` does not load dependent modules automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I tried after loading the mii module. Now it shows the error `ERROR: could not insert module r8169.ko: Invalid parameters` dmesg `[ 8157.140018] r8169: disagrees about version of symbol mii_ethtool_gset
[ 8157.140027] r8169: Unknown symbol mii_ethtool_gset (err -22)
`

Comment: @VadimStupakov Thanks a lot. You made my day. It is working now. Could you please explain, why do weplace the Module.Symvers to the build directory?. Because, I think, I have already compiled this module without Module.Symvers file in another machine before

Comment: @ebin, I think that [this document](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#426) will be enough for you :)

Comment: Thank you Vadim Stupakov. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vadim Stupakov said in the comment, Putting the `Module.symvers` file in the module source directory fixed my issue. From this [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)

```
Module versioning is enabled by the CONFIG_MODVERSIONS tag, and is used
as a simple ABI consistency check. A CRC value of the full prototype
for an exported symbol is created. When a module is loaded/used, the
CRC values contained in the kernel are compared with similar values in
the module. if they are not equal, the kernel refuses to load the
module. 
Module.symvers contains a list of all exported symbols from a kernel
build.
```

As per my understanding, `Module.symvers` is created on `make modules`. I missed out that file. When I put the appropriate `Module.symvers` in the module build directory, the module works as I expected without any errors.